# Can a database view be created from multiple selects? For instance row 1 is entirely from 1 table and row 2 is from another

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, select, view

Let's say I have 2 tables

People (id, name)
Dogs (id, name)

Can a view be created that contains all the dog names and all the people names so that for instance if I wanted to count how many entities are called Toby I'd have to query just the view?

Ideally it'd look something like

1. John - where John came from the People table
2. Toby - and Toby came from the dogs table

I'm using a PostgreSQL database but I'd be interested to know if any is able to do this.

Comment: `CREATE VIEW w AS SELECT name FROM People UNION ALL SELECT name FROM dogs` could be used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `union all` set operator to unify results from both tables:

```sql
CREATE VIEW all_names AS 
SELECT name FROM people
UNION ALL
SELECT name FROM dogs
```